# How to use specifications with aggregations?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, aggregation, specifications

Consider an EF.Core query:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
 
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyDb")
                .Options;
            using var context = new MyDbContext(options);
            SeedData(context);
 
            var query = from r in context.Regions
                        orderby r.Id
 
                        let totalOrders = context.Orders.Where(x => x.RegionId == r.Id).ToArray()
 
                        let newOrders = totalOrders.Where(x => x.RegionId == r.Id && x.OrderState == 1)
                        let soldOrders = totalOrders.Where(x => x.RegionId == r.Id && x.OrderState == 2)
                        let staleOrders = totalOrders.Where(x => x.RegionId == r.Id && x.OrderState == 3)
 
                        let newSubOrderCount = newOrders.Sum(r => r.SubOrders.Count(s => s.SubOrderState == 1))
                        let soldSubOrdersCount = soldOrders.Sum(r => r.SubOrders.Count(s => s.SubOrderState == 2))
                        let staleSubOrdersCount = staleOrders.Sum(r => r.SubOrders.Count(s => s.SubOrderState == 3))
 
                        select new
                        {
                            RegionId = r.Id,
                            TotalOrders = totalOrders.Count(),
                            SoldOrders = soldOrders.Count(),
                            StaleOrders = staleOrders.Count(),
                            NewSubOrders = newSubOrderCount,
                            SoldSubOrdersCount = soldSubOrdersCount,
                            StaleSubOrdersCount = staleSubOrdersCount
                        };
 
            var results = await query.ToArrayAsync();
            foreach(var result in results)
            {
                ConsolePrintResult(result);
            }
            
        }
 
        private static void ConsolePrintResult(dynamic result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Region ID: {result.RegionId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Total Orders: {result.TotalOrders}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Sold Orders: {result.SoldOrders}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Stale Orders: {result.StaleOrders}");
            Console.WriteLine($"New Suborders: {result.NewSubOrders}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Sold Suborders Count: {result.SoldSubOrdersCount}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Stale Suborders Count: {result.StaleSubOrdersCount}");
            Console.WriteLine($"");
        }
 
        public static void SeedData(MyDbContext context)
        {
            var rng = new Random();
 
            // create approximately 5 regions
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                var region = new Region
                {
                    Id = i
                };
 
                context.Regions.Add(region);
            }
 
            // create approximately 1,000 orders
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
            {
                var order = new Order
                {
                    Id = i,
                    RegionId = rng.Next(1, 21), // generate a random region ID between 1 and 20
                    OrderState = rng.Next(1, 4), // generate a random order state (1, 2, or 3)
                    SubOrders = new List<SubOrder>()
                };
 
                // add approximately 10 suborders to each order
                for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
                {
                    var suborder = new SubOrder
                    {
                        Id = (i - 1) * 10 + j, // generate a unique ID for each suborder
                        SubOrderState = rng.Next(1, 4), // generate a random suborder state (1, 2, or 3)
                        Order = order
                    };
 
                    order.SubOrders.Add(suborder);
                }
 
                context.Orders.Add(order);
            }
 
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
 
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubOrder> SubOrders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
    }
 
    public class Region
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
 
    public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        public Region Region { get; set; }
        public int OrderState { get; set; }
        public ICollection<SubOrder> SubOrders { get; set; }
    }
 
    public class SubOrder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SubOrderState { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public Order Order { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I wanted to utilize specification pattern (this library in particular: https://github.com/jnicolau/NSpecifications) to delegate expressions for newOrders ,soldOrders ,staleOrders into, well, specifications.

My problem is that after using `let` or `group by` statements I can no longer apply specifications, because it materializes (but the materialization is fake, see below) the subquery into an IEnumerable, e.g. this line `let totalOrders = context.Orders.Where(x => x.RegionId == r.Id).ToArray()`

Questions:

1. Why we need to call .ToArray()? It's not like we materialze entries, the query is still translated to SQL and executed on server
2. Why can we NOT call .ToArray() thus having IQueryable remaining and being able to apply a specification onto it?
3. Is there other way to still use specifications and overcome the problems listed above?

Comment: Let's start from issue that query is not performant. Then think about specifications, which I think for reporting are useless.

Comment: When query is rewritten using joins, yes it is possible to apply specifications.

Comment: ```join t in tickets on ta.Id equals t.admin into tati``` if a join is used then tati is ienumerable as well and it does not work

Comment: Better to show what you are trying to do at the end. You have tried another bad approach with `GroupJoin`.

Comment: let is a range varible,once initialized with a value, the range variable cannot be used to store another value,and it won't query until you call ToList()/ToArray method , let varible can't be type of IQueryable<T>, you could check this document :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause

Comment: Could you show how you want to use specifications?

Comment: I'd like to delegate NewOrder, SoldOrder and StaleOrder into specifications since these are used between multiple reports, e.g.:
```
var newOrderSpec = new Spec<Order>(x => x.State == 1);
...
let newOrders = totalOrders.Where(x => x.RegionId == r.Id && newOrderSpec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using some SQL provider better to rewrite query in the following way:

```cs
var regions = context.Regions.AsQueryable();
var orders = context.Orders.AsQueryable();

var subordersQuery =
    from r in regions
    join o in orders on r.Id equals o.RegionId
    from so in o.SubOrders
    group new { o, so } by r.Id
    into g
    select new
    {
        RegionId = g.Key,
        NewSubOrders = g.Sum(x => x.o.OrderState == 1 && x.so.SubOrderState == 1 ? 1 : 0),
        SoldSubOrdersCount = g.Sum(x => x.o.OrderState == 2 && x.so.SubOrderState == 2 ? 1 : 0),
        StaleSubOrdersCount = g.Sum(x => x.o.OrderState == 3 && x.so.SubOrderState == 3 ? 1 : 0)
    };

var ordersQuery =
    from r in regions
    join o in orders on r.Id equals o.RegionId
    group o by o.RegionId into g
    select new
    {
        RegionId = g.Key,
        TotalOrders = g.Count(),
        SoldOrders = g.Sum(x => x.OrderState == 2 ? 1 : 0),
        StaleOrders = g.Sum(x => x.OrderState == 3 ? 1 : 0),
    };

var query =
    from o in ordersQuery
    join so in subordersQuery on o.RegionId equals so.RegionId
    orderby o.RegionId
    select new
    {
        o.RegionId,
        o.TotalOrders,
        o.SoldOrders,
        o.StaleOrders,
        so.NewSubOrders,
        so.SoldSubOrdersCount,
        so.StaleSubOrdersCount
    };
```

In this query you can apply specification only to Regions and Orders.

Comment: This query does not respect orderState when summing subOrders while mine does. E.g. when summing staleSubOrders it gets them from orders of any state but should only count those of staleOrders. (please refer to code in 1st post, I have fixed a few typos)

Comment: My fault. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks! Did not know about ```group new``` trick. However this query, while performs well, does not provide for spec usage, and in fact now we are duplicating conditions ```OrderState == x``` for order and suborder queries

Comment: As I mentioned before specs here are useless. While I can provide solution for `SubOrders` - it needs third party library to make it work. Do not use somethings that you like, efforts to make it work can be huge.

Comment: In real application I have a lot of reports, each utilizing NewOrder definition, so delegating this to a spec seemed prudent. Am I right to understand that you can propose 3rd party library, but in fact do not recommend it since it complicates things?

Comment: SubReports is IEnumerable. You cannot apply NSpecification which creates predicate for `IQueryable` `Where` . It needs Expression Tree correction.

Comment: But is possible to create helper static methods which will be converted to SQL. But it needs third party libraries, like LINQKit.